# Why NgTemplateOutlet directive on the ng-template prints contents on page?

Tags: angular

I can understand why <1> works, but surprisingly <2> also works and prints the contents on the page, why?
Shouldn't the <2> just create another ng-template which has to be used by either createEmbeddedView or ngTemplateOutlet etc?

```
<!-- 1 -->
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="contents"></ng-container>
<!-- 2 -->
<ng-template *ngTemplateOutlet="contents"></ng-template>


<ng-template #contents>These are contents</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 2):

`ngTemplateOutlet`inserts an embedded view in the HTML node. The original node (here the `ng-container` or the `ng-template`) doesn't get displayed in the DOM at all.

For example you can also write

```
<div *ngTemplateOutlet="contents">Hello World!</div>

<ng-template #contents>These are contents</ng-template>
```

In this example the original div is not inserted into the DOM at all, but rather the `<ng-template #contents>`.